# Run VBS as administrator

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript which need to run as an administrator.

Is it possible to add some code in the script that will help with that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bypass UAC in VbScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344021/bypass-uac-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 1):

Helen, take a look at the elevate command powertoy from Microsoft

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx

Publish the code you want to run, then we can give more advise.

The anwser [Bypass UAC in VbScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344021/bypass-uac-in-vbscript) from the comment above works also but has it drawback, i also use the tools RUNAS and PSEXEC from systernals.