# How can I change never notify in 'user account control settings'?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling UAC programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682182/disabling-uac-programmatically)

How can I change never notify in 'user account control settings' by c#?
by manual : 
User Accounts -> user account control settings -> change by scall bar to 'never notify'.

(I need it for automated integration tests )

Comment: @HasanKhan: you will only be able to change it when you are executing as an Administrator. They are all powerful anyway and should know what they are doing.

Comment: After all, with years of running as administrator in previous Windows versions, users have clearly demonstrated their grasp of "what they are doing", and as a consequence, Windows has a really good reputation as a secure OS. @sari k : please ensure that you prompt the user VERY clearly about the changes you want to make and allow whatever it is you are writing to function correctly w/o requiring UAC to be disabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an Administrator you could change the appropriate registry key [using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Have a look at this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7/83678#83678

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
key.SetValue("EnableLUA", "0");
key.Close();
```