# WPF: Generating Custom MessageBox instead of Windows MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to run an application from my code, that application can only be run with administrative rights. I am able to run the application successfully with the following code.

```
start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.Arguments = drive;
start.Verb = "runas";
start.FileName = filepath;
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
start.CreateNoWindow = false;
using (exeProcess = Process.Start(start))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Following MessageBox appears;

[image: Screenshot of MessageBox]

What I want to do is I want to suppress above mentioned Windows Messagebox, and show my own designed Messagebox. Kindly guide me how can I do it.

Comment: The only way I know you can do this is to start your program with administration rights. Then all programs it starts will be with administration rights without asking for permission. But I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: @R.Rusev Not a solution which I am looking for

Comment: Some useful information about UAC and processes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20872219/856777

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you want to do is [Disabling UAC programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682182/disabling-uac-programmatically) which is not possible according to the link.

Comment: No I just want to display my own message in messagebox

Comment: @user3069453 well you can't. It's a security issue. If you can change the dialog you can change the text/buttons so they say something differnt which is almost the same as removing the window all together.